# What is the difference between Total order sorting and secondary sorting in map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to explore Total order sorting and secondary sorting. Can any one explain what kind of use cases fits in both these models?

Answer (score 1):

Secondary sort is a technique that allows the MapReduce programmer to control the order that the values show up within a reduce function call.

Sorting Map Output Keys across all the reducers is called TotalOrder Sorting.

Please have a look at following links,

https://www.quora.com/What-is-secondary-sort-in-Hadoop-and-how-does-it-work

http://blog.ditullio.fr/2016/01/04/hadoop-basics-total-order-sorting-mapreduce/